# Tile scenes side by side in Windows 7 as virtual machine

Tags: keyboard, windows, window-manager, virtualization

I am using Windows 7 as virtual machine under Mac OS...

The keyboard shortcuts of Windows become difficult because of the Mac keyboard...

For instance, I am used to tiling scenes in Windows by `Windows icon key` + `right arrow` or `Windows icon key` + `left arrow`, which moves the scene to the right half of the window or the left half...

However, I can't find `Windows icon key` now on the Mac keyboard...

So, could anyone tell me what is the keyboard shortcut to move scenes in Windows 7 as virtual machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For VMWare the command key acts as the windows key, so command+right and command+left will do what you want.

If this isn't working, you might not have the VMWare guest tools installed on the virtual machine.  There are instructions here:

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/new_guest_tools_ws.html

Comment: I have seen that on some web pages, but command+right or command+left does not work...

Comment: @SoftTimur It works for mine.  I know this because it annoys me to no end.  What virtualization software are you using?

Comment: .. and did you install the guest VM tools for your virtualization software?

Comment: What is `guest VM tools`? I have installed VMware, so that I can run Windows 7 as a virtual machine under Mac OS...

Comment: @SoftTimur The VM tools are drivers so Windows can better use the VM program's emulated hardware (like network or graphics).

Comment: @SoftTimur I've edited my question to add a link to instructions for installing the vmware guest tools.  Once you've installed (or reinstalled) the tools the keyboard shortcuts should work as indicated.